# How To Call Another Function Concurrently, During Wait() C++

Tags: c++, wait, iot, mbed

I have a class where I have 2 functions as below;

```
// Function to calculate the sum and average temperature
float read_samples(float *data, int num_samples)
{
    float sum = 0.0;
    float average = 0.0;

    for(int i = 1; i < num_samples; i++ ) {
        data[i] = temperature.read();
        sum = sum + data[i];
        wait(1);
    }
    average = sum / (num_samples - 1);
    return average;
}

// Main Function that is called on running the application
int main()
{
    int num_samples = 12 / 1;
    float data[num_samples];
    //sw.fall(read_samples(data, num_samples));
    while(1) {
        wait(12);
        float result = read_samples(data, num_samples);
        lcd.printf("%.2f\n", result);
        //data[0];
    }
}
```

When I call the "wait(12);" method in Main, I want the code to at the same time to go execute the "read_samples" method while waiting, and when the "read_samples" is done return the value computed, then go ahead to display the computed result in the Main function. The computation should be during the 12 seconds while waiting.

However, what is happening right now is that during the 12 seconds while waiting, no execution is carried out, so after waiting for 12 seconds it goes to call the "read_samples" method and carries out execution for another 11 seconds. So the total time spent to display the next result is (12 + 11) 23 seconds. Please, how do I write my code to execute the "read_samples" method during the 12 seconds wait?

Comment: What is `wait` here? Where does `S` come from?

Comment: Look at [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and [`<future>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/future).

Comment: Use worker threads to run code concurrently

Comment: This is what `std::async` is for.  Launch an asynchronous task and then go about your business.  When you are ready for the the result then you call `get` from the returned `future`.

Comment: If the main thread is waiting for the sample collection, why go asynchronous at all?

Comment: @tadman I just updated the question, S has the value of 1 second. Wait() tells the code to pause execution for the number of seconds inserted in the Wait() function.

Comment: One easy way to do it would be to record the current time into a local variable, then call read_samples(), then record the current time again into a second local variable.  Then subtract the first timestamp from the second one, and wait() for (12 seconds minus that delta)

Comment: What user4581301 asks is very relevant with the objective you have posted so far. So unless you have more plans... Why 'Wait`?

Comment: I find no 'S' or 's' in the post code, only the comments?

Comment: @2785528 I have replaced the value of S. S stands for 1 second.

Comment: @lakeweb If I don't have to wait, can you suggest any other way to run the read_samples() function while I am waiting for 12 seconds.

Comment: I don't know what OS/development system you are using. `wait` sounds like [std::sleep_until](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until). If you want to block your main thread while you take a sample every second, that is what `read_samples` will do. Sleeping in `main` is not needed and gets in the way of your objective.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `read_samples` in a separate thread. E.g.:

```
static float average = 0.0f;

// Function to calculate the sum and average temperature
void read_samples()
{
    int num_samples = 12 / 1;
    float data[num_samples];

    float sum = 0.0;

    for(int i = 1; i < num_samples; i++ ) {
        data[i] = temperature.read();
        sum = sum + data[i];
        wait(1);
    }
    average = sum / (num_samples - 1);
}

// Main Function that is called on running the application
int main()
{
    //sw.fall(read_samples(data, num_samples));
    while(1) {
        Thread sampleThread;
        sampleThread.start(&read_samples);

        wait(12);

        lcd.printf("%.2f\n", result);
        //data[0];
    }
}
```

You'll want to guard access to the `average` through a [Mutex](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.11/apis/mutex.html).